# Deleting element from linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list

I got some stuff working but still i cant get last element delete working it just leaves garbage at it's place instead of deleting it. I know this code doesn't look good but that's all what I could do based on my knowledge as for now :x. So if somebody could help me with getting my delete for last element work or tell me what I'm doing wrong here would be great

```
struct item {
    char item_name[30];
    char item_state[30];
    float item_price;
    char item_status[30];
    float item_price_if_not;
    struct item *next;
};
struct client {
    char client_name[30];
    char client_last_name[30];
    struct item *item_data;
    struct client *next;
};

void DeleteClient2(struct client *temp,struct client **head) {
    struct client *prev=*head;
    struct client *current = *head;
    struct item *currentitem = (*head)->item_data,*save;
    if(temp== *head) {
        while(currentitem != NULL) {
            save = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }
        free(temp);
        temp->item_data = NULL;
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
    }
    else if(temp->next == NULL) {
        while(currentitem != NULL)  {
            save = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }
        temp->item_data = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else if(temp != *head && temp->next != NULL) {
        while(prev->next != temp) {
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        prev->next = temp->next;
        while(currentitem != NULL) {
            save = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }
        temp->item_data = NULL;
        free(temp);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed most of code if somebody is willing to help it would be great, it seems my code is not deleting last element first one and middle seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deleting item data from the head rather than from temp.

Comment: Added a bit to what I had before most of stuff seems to be working expect last one if I delete last one when i print my list I see garbage instead of this node

Comment: I can't see where you are nullify ing the next pointer that points to the last element. Is that what's wrong now?